# How does Santa travel to other galaxies?

Tags: ftl, santa-claus, galactic

NORAD has concluded from their observations of Santa that he must have some faster-than-light travel mechanism and space-time warping capabilities. However, the [Santa Goes to Space](https://sacmuseum.org/event/santa-goes-to-space/) event at the Strategic Air Command and Aerospace Museum seems to indicate that Santa has visited a galaxy far, far away.

Even with the imaginable means of FTL travel and space-time warping, it is hard to conceive of a way Santa could have visited another galaxy and returned in any reasonable amount of time.

How did Santa accomplish this feat?

Bonus: Why would Santa want to visit other galaxies?

Comment: Ho, ho, hold on there new users! If you are confused by the jolly tone of this question, check the [tag:santa-claus] tag and observe the spirit of the season. (Of course, if you prefer you can humbug--I mean vote to close.)

Comment: For muggles, this question is functionally equivalent to "What theoretical means could be used for intergalactic travel within a human lifetime?"

Comment: I think this question belongs in the worldbuilding exchange

Comment: Your basic mistake is assuming that Santa is a single person.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because my middle name is scrooge

Comment: @JCRM: Grinch! :(

Comment: @called2voyage "Check the [tag:santa-claus] tag and observe the spirit of the season." Tag has no wiki to inform users of what that spirit of the season is. >_>

Comment: He simply dials up his sled to warp 10 and visits every point in the universe simultaneously [reference](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Threshold_\(episode\))

Comment: "A Long Time Ago At A North Pole Far, Far Away..."

Answer (score 43):

This picture seems to imply that interstellar travel planning is enough of a headache without throwing in other galaxies.

[image]

However this picture may provide a clue: perhaps the galaxy(ies) are serviced by local Santa equivalents.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, maybe he was visiting a Santa equivalent? http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Santa_Claus Still leaves us with the question of how the journey was accomplished.

Comment: @called2voyage no doubt some form of wrap-drive.

Comment: The guy in the red suit is **not** our beloved Santa Claus. Ours has two arms, just like the teal Santa (obviously ET) in the second picture.

Comment: I don't know why Emshwiller put the extra arms on him in this series of cover paintings from the 50s.  I do know, however, that I'd *kill* to have that coffee maker.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The tyranny of the coffee equation - the more grounds you put in, the less effective each ground is, so you have to keep adding more to really make the coffee stronger.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like he had the Space Gem. This funny webcomic already spilled the secret:

[image]

(found at http://pvponline.com/comic/2017-12-20)

Answer (score 9):

### Time travel

Even with "warp" or any other FTL technology (including the alcubierre drive) backwards time travel is not just possible, but *necessary*. From Santa's reference frame, millions of year surely pass each Christmas (which explains why he is so old), whereas from our reference frame, it will only be a day. It will also appear from our reference frame that Santa is bouncing forward and backwards in time delivering presents.

Answer (score 5):

In the Start Trek universe (happened in Star Trek Voyager), Santa could break the transwarp barrier to visit other galaxies:

> Achieving warp 10 would allow a person to be in every point in the
>   universe, simultaneously.

[Threshold (episode)](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Threshold_(episode))

There are some side effects though like accelerated form of natural evolution. This side effect could be an answer to your bonus question, he might look to becoming the ultimate human being. This could also explain the depictions of a Santa with four arms in Organic Marble's post. Not sure about the time travel implications though.

Food for thought.

Update: Apparently Darren H beat me to it 7 hours ago with this theory, sorry I didn't notice it. I hope my explanation to the reasons is some kind of contribution.

Answer (score 4):

> Bonus: Why would Santa want to visit other galaxies?

I can't imagine all other galaxies in the universe are devoid of children, nor can I imagine that all children of other galaxies are naughty. There must be nice children in other galaxies who deserve Christmas presents.

Now pure speculation leads me to suggest that it's possible, even likely, that there are galaxies where the cookie ingredients available are much more flavorful and offer amazing flavors not available in the Milky Way. For all we know, the Milky Way could be Santa's *least* favorite galaxy to visit, and right now there is a question on the Andromedan Stack Exchange asking why Santa would ever visit the Milky Way.

Comment: That would almost be cross-galactic-posting! :-)