# Where is the LC-19 launch console now?

Tags: nasa, history, museum-exhibits

Julia Bergeron's [recent tweet](https://twitter.com/julia_bergeron/status/1017800366883209221) from Florida shows an electronics console that looks to be mid-20th century. Above it is written `LC-19` but there are other `LC` signs as well, and this does not look like a setting where spacecraft are launched now.

Is this in some museum of Space history?

I suppose it could be in the Skycraft store in the replied [tweet](https://twitter.com/julia_bergeron/status/1017609725544947712) but it looks more like a museum or educational center to me.

[image]

Comment: Don't you tweet with Julia ? :)

Comment: @Conelisinspace I don't participate in any social media at all, at least not interactively. I just ran across a link to this tweet while doing research on Mr. Steven for [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28424/12102).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exhibit in the [Air Force Space and Missile Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Space_and_Missile_Museum) at [Cape Canaveral Air Force Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral_Air_Force_Station).

This is a picture from the museum's [website](http://afspacemuseum.org/displays/PeriscopeCushion/) showing the same exhibit.

[image]

Comment: Your links so often lead me to new places, thank you! [What do these GPS-related emblems represent? Does one of them show "Marvin the Martian"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29434/12102)

Comment: It's a good museum mostly because of its awesome "rocket garden". It's hard to get to though, because it's behind the gates.  I think the general public can pay to see it as part of a tour at the KSC visitor complex, but that info might be out of date.

Comment: I think this might be a virtual tour. It's not running on my laptop but that may be because of Flash issues. http://www.afspacemuseum.org/virtual/ So far I can't find a tour in google maps either. Wow, I'd really really love to see this! http://www.afspacemuseum.org/images/2018SpaceCollectibleShowPoster.jpg I wonder if they have the rocket-shaped coffee maker you commented on last year? (was that you, I can't remember)

Comment: indeed it was! https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24121/12102

Comment: The virtual tour doesn't work for me either - I don't allow Flash on our home systems :(  I'll see if I can spin up a virtual machine and take a look.

Comment: I was able to get it to work in a Windows 7 virtual machine. I skimmed the virtual tour.  This launch complex stuff is in the part labeled "History Center".

Comment: egads I should have accepted this a year ago, sorry for the delay!

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the accept.