# What do these GPS-related emblems represent? Does one of them show "Marvin the Martian"?

Tags: history, gps, identify-this-object, space-art, cape-canaveral

The Wikipedia page linked in @OrganicMarble's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29433/12102) about the [Air Force Space and Missile Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Space_and_Missile_Museum) contains the image below, of a (now retired) [GPS monitoring station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GPS_monitor_station.jpg). To the right of the station itself is a sign that says

### Monitor Station GPS Antenna 1984-2007

### On Time, On Target

and shows three different emblems, each with a motto or other words on it.

Does anyone recognize these three symbols or can guess what organizations they are associated with?

Does the green-helmeted individual in the lower just coincidentally resemble [Marvin the Martian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpWyQ.jpg)? Read further about Marvin in this [authoritative answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149565/51174), and [watch him in action](https://youtu.be/QuUJfYcn3V4?t=22).

[image: Monitoring Station GPS Antenna sign]

[image: Marvin the Martian]

[image: Monitoring Station GPS Antenna]

Comment: Maybe. In http://www.atr.samhsa.gov/Resources/2011_weekly/2011_12_29/WH_2011_12_29.html, NASA notes "Marvin the Martian became our mascot", but that was in 2008. https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/164449main_spinoff_06.pdf notes "Since 1948, [...], Marvin
the Martian has been attempting to blow up the Earth
with his Illudium Q-36 Explosive Space Modulator, since
our Blue Planet blocks his view of Venus.", suggesting they at least know who he is.

Comment: Your first link is related to the US Department of Health and Human Services, but I don't see any connection to NASA there at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The "Master of Space" griffon patch is the [50th Space Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50th_Space_Wing)'s emblem.
- The potential "Marvin" patch is an emblem from the 1st Detachment, [2nd Space Operations Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2d_Space_Operations_Squadron), an element of the 50th Space Wing.

> The unit had one geographically separated unit, Detachment 1, at Cape
>   Canaveral Air Force Station, Florida. It was responsible for
>   maintenance of a GPS Ground Antenna, Monitor Station, and various
>   operational test assets. It is now discontinued, though contractors
>   remained to perform the mission.

- The "compass rose" patch is an emblem of the Air Force [Global Positioning System Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_Systems_Directorate).

Whether Marvin was intended may remain a mystery - although it seems likely to me.

Comment: Chuck Jones has a lot to answer for...

Comment: Oh, look, I might get one of these for my golfing cap...http://usmilitarypatches.com/gallery/displayimage.php?album=14&pid=16442